# Mapping two tables 0..n in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, mapping, one-to-one

I have a table Users

```
CREATE TABLE "USERS" (
    "ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ,
    "LOGINNAME" VARCHAR2 (150) NOT NULL )
```

and I have a second table SpecialUsers. No UserId can occur twice in the SpecialUsers table, and only a small subset of the ids of users in the Users table are contained in the SpecialUsers table.

```
CREATE TABLE "SPECIALUSERS" (
    "USERID" NUMBER NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT "PK_SPECIALUSERS" PRIMARY KEY ("USERID") )

ALTER TABLE "SPECIALUSERS" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_SPECIALUSERS_USERID" FOREIGN KEY ("USERID") 
REFERENCES "USERS" ("ID") 
/
```

Mapping the Users table in Hibernate works ok

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.initech.domain">
    <class name="com.initech.User" table="USERS">

        <id name="id" column="ID" type="java.lang.Long">
            <meta attribute="use-in-tostring">true</meta>
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">SEQ_USERS_ID</param>
            </generator>
        </id>

        <property name="loginName" column="LOGINNAME" type="java.lang.String" not-null="true">
            <meta attribute="use-in-tostring">true</meta>
        </property>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

But I'm struggling in creating the mapping for the SpecialUsers table. All the examples (e.g. in Hibernate documentation) in Internet I found don't have this type of self-reference. I tried a mapping like this:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.initech.domain">
    <class name="com.initech.User" table="SPECIALUSERS">        

        <id name="id" column="USERID">
            <meta attribute="use-in-tostring">true</meta>
            <generator class="foreign">
                <param name="property">user</param>
            </generator>
        </id>

        <one-to-one name="user" class="User"/>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

but got the error

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: 
Duplicate class/entity mapping com.initech.User
```

How should I map the SpecialUsers table? What I need on the application level is a list of the User objects contained in the SpecialUsers table.

Comment: Why not just add a 'special' field to the USERS table?

Comment: I considered that, but considering that there are very few "special" users (currently one) and very many users, it didn't seem right. Long-term, it would also make the Users table unclear if every small property, which applies only to a small subset of users, would be added directly to the Users table. A further reason is also that if the "special" users should have more attributes related to their "specialness" in the future, it is easy to extend the SpecialUsers table.

Comment: why do you think there is a 0..n relation somewhere? Your physical model doesn't reflect that, it represent a pure parent-child hierarchy (i.e. inheritance). Am I missing something?

Comment: @Pascal, please feel free to correct the title if you find a better description. I guess the logic was that for each user there is 0 to 1 SpecialUsers - or alternatively said, some users are special users but not all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How should I map the SpecialUsers table?

According to the structure of your `USERS` and `SPECIALUSERS` tables, you have a [Table per subclass](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tablepersubclass) hierarchy and **it is perfectly possible to map this kind of hierarchy with Hibernate**.

First, make sure that `SpecialUser` *inherits* from `User` at the object model level (this is an inheritance relationship, not a self-reference).

```
public class SpecialUser extends User { 
}
```

Then, declare a `<joined-subclass>` element in the `User`'s mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.initech.domain">
    <class name="com.initech.User" table="USERS">

        <id name="id" column="ID" type="java.lang.Long">
            <meta attribute="use-in-tostring">true</meta>
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">SEQ_USERS_ID</param>
            </generator>
        </id>

        <property name="loginName" column="LOGINNAME" type="java.lang.String" not-null="true">
            <meta attribute="use-in-tostring">true</meta>
        </property>

        <joined-subclass name="com.initech.SpecialUser" table="SPECIALUSERS">
            <key column="USERID"/>
        </joined-subclass>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

> What I need on the application level is a list of the User objects contained in the SpecialUsers table.

The following HQL query would return all the `SpecialUser` (which are `User` too):

```
from SpecialUser
```

If later you need to add columns to the `SPECIALUSERS` table, add the corresponding attributes to the `SpecialUser` class and map them inside the `<joined-subclass>` element. Refer to the provided link (to the documentation) for the details.

Answer (score 1):

If you really have to use a second table, you must map it to a new class. Hibernate can always only map one table to one class.

Alternatively, add a column to the user table which says "this user is special". If that is not an option, create a view which joins the two tables and thus simulates this column. Then, you can select users by this column.

If you go the two class way, you must load a list of the special users and do the mapping in your application.

[EDIT] Maybe you should look into parent-child relations. In your case, the user is the parent and its roles are the children. So every user has 0..n roles which are mapped in a different table. You can then use this HQL

```
from User u where :role in elements(u.roles)
```

to find all users with a certain role. But most of the time, you'll have a specific user and just need to query whether she has a certain role.

Comment: Aaroon, while the initial title of the question was pretty confusing, I don't think that your edit reflects the initial intend (it matches your answer but this is not what the OP was asking for IMHO). And the physical model doesn't represent a 0..n relation BTW, it's a pure inheritance relation.